# Why does my pandas dataframe have two headers?

Tags: python, pandas

```
def get_all_rows(conn):
df6 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Outofcountry", conn)
print(df6)
return



       ComputerName              ConnectTime        lastExtIP  latestCountry          latestRegion    latestCity             Name  CurrentLogonUser  LastLogonUser  PrimaryUser    UserName
0      ComputerName      ConnectTime_decimal        lastExtIP  latestCountry          latestRegion    latestCity             Name  CurrentLogonUser  LastLogonUser  PrimaryUser  UserName\n
```

Id like to be able to get rid of the 2nd row...
this is the code block:

```
def get_all_rows(conn):
    df6 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Outofcountry", conn)
    print(df6)
    return


d1 = pd.read_csv("CS_Out_Of_Country.csv", mangle_dupe_cols='True', encoding='windows-1252')
```

i tried adding this and with False but it doesnt do anything

would like it to be just one output for the header:

```
   ComputerName              ConnectTime        lastExtIP  latestCountry          latestRegion    latestCity             Name  CurrentLogonUser  LastLogonUser  PrimaryUser    UserName
```

Comment: Does that second header exist in the database? If you run the SQL query `SELECT * FROM Outofcountry LIMIT 1`, without using Pandas, what's the output?

Comment: it prints two lines, how can make it to only print 1?

Comment: Then you have a row in your database which is the same as the header. Probably something was screwed up when this table was created.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the header appears two times in your SQL table. You could dust do:

```
df6.drop([0], inplace=True)
```

Comment: sorry, im not sure where to put this, the main question is why is it happening?

Comment: You can put it inside the function after you assigned the dataframe to your SQL query, and I've answered your question, it seems like your SQL table has a duplicate header so the second header appears in the dataframe as the first row.

Comment: def get_all_rows(conn):
    df6 = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Outofcountry", conn)
    df7 = df6.drop([0], inplace=True)
    print(df7)
    return

Comment: prints None when i do print(df7)

Comment: i got it working with df5 = df4.drop([0])

Comment: Right. But you don't need the "inplace=True" if you're assigning a new variable for the dataframe.